# bash -gt command with pgrep & wc

Tags: bash, unix, wc, grep

I'm trying to run `[ pgrep mongo | wc -l -gt 2]` to see if there are more than 2 mongo processes running, but I keep getting this error -bash: [: missing `]'

I feel like I'm missing something simple here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need command substitution and a space before `]`:

```
[ $(pgrep mongo | wc -l) -gt 2 ]
```

`$(...)` is the syntax for [**command substitution**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

Comment: Yup! Worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Besides using command substitution, it is a good idea to use [arithmetic expression](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr) in that case:

```
(( $(pgrep mongo | wc -l) > 2 ))
```